# Create an instance of Fractional using my own constructor (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, instance

I'm trying to create my own instance of Fractional using my own constructor "Z95" which is defined as :

```
data Z95 = Z95 Classe deriving (Eq)
```

I already defined an instance of Num using this constructor but for no reason the Fractional one doesn't work :/

```
instance Num Z95 where
  (+) (Z95 a) (Z95 b) = z95 (representant (plusMod 95 a b))
  (*) (Z95 a) (Z95 b) = z95 (representant (mulMod 95 a b))
  fromInteger n = z95 n
  negate (Z95 x) = z95 (-(representant x) + 95)
```

So, here's the Fractional instance :

```
instance Fractional Z95 where
  (/) c1 c2 = (Z95 c1) * (Z95 (invMod c2)
```

When i try to load my file into GHCI it tells me :

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

and this message appears even if I change the code which is just after my instance declaration.

Comment: You shouldn't make it a Fractional, but an Integral, since Z95 is more of an integer type.

Comment: I have to make it a Fractional so I can use a function that allows me to reverse a matrix right after. I'm not the author of the beggining of the code so I didn't searched to optimize this part ^^ but thanks I'll check that :)

Comment: Fractional might actually be the right thing for you, if you want the inverse of multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, you have mismatched brackets:

```
(/) c1 c2 = (Z95 c1) * (Z95 (invMod c2) 
                       ^
```

Comment: I'm feeling so dumb right now >< I think i should go to sleep. Thanks anyway ^^